# React Native nested animated flatlist scale not working for 0th index item

Tags: react-native

I'm created a nested animated flatlist (horizontal inside of vertical) and I've got it to work so to speak: the animations for every item in the horizontal flatlist other than the first index works as expected and the vertical flatlist works well too. The problem arises when scrolling horizontally, the first item doesn't get the scale animation because it has the y-axis scaling assigned to it's scale property.

I tried assigning both scaleX and scaleY props but that didn't work:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
  FlatList,
  Animated,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import data from "../data";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const MARGIN_TOP = 200;
const IMAGE_WIDTH = width * 0.75;
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = height * 0.5;
const CIRCLE_HEIGHT = 100;
const CIRCLE_WIDTH = 100;

const Item = ({
  scrollY,
  scrollX,
  horizontalIndex,
  verticalIndex,
  item,
  direction,
}) => {
  const horizontalInputRange = [
    (horizontalIndex - 1) * IMAGE_WIDTH,
    horizontalIndex * IMAGE_WIDTH,
    (horizontalIndex + 1) * IMAGE_WIDTH,
  ];
  const verticalInputRange = [
    (verticalIndex - 1) * IMAGE_HEIGHT,
    verticalIndex * IMAGE_HEIGHT,
    (verticalIndex + 1) * IMAGE_HEIGHT,
  ];
  const scale = scrollX.interpolate({
    inputRange: horizontalInputRange,
    outputRange: [0.4, 1, 0.4],
  });
  const scaleY = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: verticalInputRange,
    outputRange: [0.4, 1, 0.4],
  });
  const circleScale = scrollX.interpolate({
    inputRange: horizontalInputRange,
    outputRange: [0.5, 1, 0.5],
  });
  const circleOpacity = scrollX.interpolate({
    inputRange: horizontalInputRange,
    outputRange: [0.1, 1, 0.1],
  });
  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.circle,
            {
              backgroundColor: item.color,
              transform: [{ scale: circleScale }],
              opacity: circleOpacity,
            },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
      <Animated.Image
        source={item.imageUri}
        style={[
          styles.img,
          {
            transform:
              horizontalIndex === 0 ? [{ scale: scaleY }] : [{ scale }],
            marginBottom: verticalIndex === data.length - 1 ? 400 : 0,
            marginRight: horizontalIndex === data.length - 1 ? 100 : 0,
          },
        ]}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const ItemColorScreen = () => {
  const scrollY = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const scrollX = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container1}>
      <StatusBar hidden style="auto" />
      <Image
        source={require("../assets/ball.jpg")}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />
      <Animated.FlatList
        style={{ paddingTop: 200 }}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${Math.random() + item.key}`}
        renderItem={({ item, index: verticalIndex }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <Animated.FlatList
                style={{ paddingLeft: 50 }}
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={(item) => `${Math.random() + item.key}`}
                horizontal
                renderItem={({ item, index: horizontalIndex }) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <Item
                        scrollY={scrollY}
                        scrollX={scrollX}
                        horizontalIndex={horizontalIndex}
                        verticalIndex={verticalIndex}
                        item={item}
                        direction="horizontal"
                      />
                    </>
                  );
                }}
                pagingEnabled
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                onScroll={Animated.event(
                  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
                  { useNativeDriver: true }
                )}
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
              />
              {/* <Item scrollY={scrollY} index={index} item={item} /> */}
            </>
          );
        }}
        pagingEnabled
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: true }
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ItemColorScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container1: {
    height,
    width,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  img: {
    height: IMAGE_HEIGHT,
    width: IMAGE_WIDTH,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    alignSelf: "center",
    // backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  circle: {
    height: CIRCLE_HEIGHT,
    width: CIRCLE_WIDTH,
    borderRadius: CIRCLE_HEIGHT,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 130,
    left: 130,
  },
});
```

If any devs want to re-create, I'll give assets and what-not, I wasn't sure how to recreate on codesandbox